# POST 400 (bad Request) Error

Tags: http, post

my environment is below

ASP.NET CORE 2.0

Here is Test Function

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Home");
    }
```

and I use PostMan to send Post Data
http://localhost:00000/test/test

and always have 400 bad request... why?

[error message]

```
headers:Headers
ok:false
status:400
statusText:"Bad Request"
type:2
url:"http://localhost:57230/account/register"
_body:""
```

**[Updated]**
I found solution.. but have new error XD

```
 headers:Headers
 ok:false
 status:500
 statusText:"Internal Server Error"
 type:2
 url:"http://localhost:57227/account/register"
 _body:
```

**[Update]**
Solved...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis

Comment: Can you show us your post data?

Comment: Hi in the future please do let us know ~how~ you solved the issue, so that anyone searching this can gain more information on the problem and the solution as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar situation where the Form POST was routed to the correct controller, but then the controller returned an empty page (400 Error). The controller didn't even execute any code within it.

The issue appears to be the following:

If you do not place `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` just after the `<form>` tag in your CSHTML, if you use `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]` or `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` the Controller will return an empty page without output or console warning.

So it appears preventing cross-site or cross-session(?) attacks through HTML forms is working as intended.

Comment: I found a way before and I using Angular together :)
but anyway Thanks for answering.